# How to understand Tornado gen.coroutine

Tags: python, tornado

I'm just a newbie to Tornado but not Python.

**I'm trying to write an async client for CouchDB(using couchdb package).**

After 1 day research/Googling, I found every posts just simply using HttpAsyncClient for example and not telling why and how **gen.coroutine** works.
The source code just too complicated for me understand cause decorator after decorator HttpAsyncClient is a bad example to me...

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, for ma it was only after reading source, that I (partially) understood the logic

It sort of works like this if you have decorated `somefunction()` with `tornado.gen`:

1. in statement `yield somefunction()` somefunction() is actually called
2. Since it's a wrapper, not your code is executed but `tornado.coroutine.gen`. It runs your code until the first `yield` in `somefunction`
3. If a Future(placehodler) is yielded(back to decorator code!), tornado says: "OK, when this future resolves, schedule a task(IOLoop callback) for IOLoop so that it calls some `another_callback()`".
4. To track how far the execution of your `somefunction()` is gone, Tornado maintains a special object called `Runner`. It remembers the last `yield` statement which blocked the execution of your `somefunction()` and is first run when decorator `gen` is executed.
5. After point 3., where Future was "registered", this Runner returns from its main `run()` method and decorator exits, returning Future of its own
6. When Future from point 3. is ready, it adds a task to IOLoop, which then calls `another_callback`. Latter is a special callback created by Tornado, shortly put, it `run()`s the same Runner as was running when in point 3. a newly resolved Future was yielded.
7. Runner uses `.send()` method to inject a value of newly resolved Future back to your `somefuncion`, which cause ait to be assigned to a variable (if any) in your function in statement like this:

   ```
   a = yield some_other_coroutine_for_example_async_client_fetch()
   ```

OK, that's a gist, there are lots of deatails, some of which I canot wrap my head around, especially, exception handling, but HTH

Comment: Yeah, exception handling is a very interesting part.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer covers a lot. I just want to let u know a simpler abstraction.
@Gen.coroutine

```
res = yield foo()
```

The coroutine idea is asyncly execute `foo()`, especially when foo takes a lot IO or network job.
The yield could fire up the `foo()` execution and transfer control out , say,  to caller. And it leaves a Runner to register this `foo()` task as a future obj. Then when `foo()` successfully return a result, this is magic happen, the Runner will send the result back, in the form of yield statement execution result (tell the diff between value yield and yield statement execution result).